# Smoothness of the solution of 1D diffusion equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, smoothness

How do I show that the solution of 1D diffusion equation is smooth for all t>0? I do know that in order to show a nonlinear PDE, for example Burger's equation, develops corners (instead of smooth solution), I just need to show the crossing of characteristics, or find the Riemann invariants and proceeds from there etc. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 1D diffusion equation? Do you have a particular example in mind? One can certainly form singularities in non-linear diffusion equations. // Also, parabolic PDEs and hyperbolic ones (Burger's equation, for example) are qualitatively very different. Your question needs to be a lot more precise to be answerable.